# Using PHP code causes formatting problems

Tags: php, internet-explorer, formatting

So I have a .php webpage, which includes a PHP script at the top for a login system.
Under this is the HTML to display the webpage. Now in Firefox or chrome it displays fine, but in Internet explorer the website appears shocking. I have found the formatting is correct when the PHP is removed. Here is the PHP code used at the top of the page:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!session_is_registered(myusername)){
header("location:http://www.mvaeng.com.au/Login");
}
$myusername = $_SESSION["myusername"];
$mypassword = $_SESSION["mypassword"];

$host="localhost"; // Host name
include 'DATA.php';
$db_name="mvaengco_Loginsystem"; // Database name
$tbl_name="Members"; // Table name


mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or
die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die(mysql_error());


$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and
password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

if(!($count==1)){
    header("location:http://www.mvaeng.com.au/Login");
}
$htaccess = 'Files/.htaccess';
$ip .= $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$line1ht .= "order deny,allow \r\n";
$line2ht .= "deny from all \r\n";
$line3ht .= "allow from $ip \r\n";
file_put_contents($htaccess, $line1ht);
file_put_contents($htaccess, $line2ht, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
file_put_contents($htaccess, $line3ht, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

?>
```

And the first part of the HTML code beneath the PHP code:

```
<head>
        <title>Client File System - Logged In</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <link href="http://mvaeng.com.au/css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet"      type="text/css" />

        <link href="http://mvaeng.com.au/css/layout.css" rel="stylesheet"      type="text/css" />

        <link href="http://mvaeng.com.au/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"      type="text/css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mvaeng.com.au/js/dropdown.js">     </script>

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"      type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="jquery.easing.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="jqueryFileTree.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link href="jqueryFileTree.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"      media="screen" />
        <script type="text/javascript">  
            var x="../../MASTER/Files/";  

            function openFile(file) {
                var fileA=file.replace("/","/BIN_1/");
                    window.location = fileA;
            }  

            $(document).ready( function() {

                $('#fileTree').fileTree({ root: '../../BIN_1/Files/',      script: 'connectors/jqueryFileTree.php' }, function(file) { 
                    openFile(file);
                });


            });
        </script>

    </head>
```

So, how do I fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: This makes no sense - PHP will not be shown on the server. Can you show the first lines of the final HTML code that is sent to the browser? Also what exactly looks wrong?

Comment: every section looks cramped up the top of the page in IE

Comment: Show some HTML code. This is impossible to answer otherwise. The problem could have a thousand different reasons.

Comment: so what does it look like in ie

Answer (score 0):

Well, IE is a really annoying browser. It interprets the html differently, especially when it comes to blank areas, or whitespaces...

Anyhow, If cross-browser compatibility is really important for you, i suggest you design the page using properly placed div's (or another matching element), and place the text inside.
The php code probably causes some unwanted whitespaces that are ruining your html output, and IE doesn't know how to hanle...

Answer (score 0):

Try using ob_start() at the beginning of your php script, and ob_flush() at the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you have other pieces of PHP within your html, then removing the top part in IE could produce the change you're seeing. Other than that, I don't see what visual effect the presence or lack thereof of the top PHP code would produce.

On a side not, you NEED to switch to mysqli. mysql in PHP was used in the 90s and is no longer a proper way to code any serious program. The sooner you make the change, the less you'll have to change later on.
mysqli really isn't that different. Just look at some examples and you'll catch on easily enough.

Comment: there is one small piece of PHP code in the HTML which is just       <?php echo $myusername ?>